# MySQL Boolean Full-Text Searches: Change Default Operator to "and"

Tags: mysql, boolean, full-text-search, innodb

(no operator)

By default (when neither + nor - is specified) the word is optional

---

How can I change this behavior to:

(no operator)

All words are required -> logical AND search

---

Example:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('MySQL Tricks' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

should only find id 4,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM articles
    WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+MySQL +Tricks' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Note the `+` *prefix* on each word that is 'required'.  The '+' is not a 'binary operator'.

Comment: I want wo achieve it without modifying the query.

Comment: Sorry, `FULLTEXT` has limitations.  If you are working with some 3rd party software that is 'generating' the `SELECT`, gripe at them.